# 配列のサイズによるエラー

Tags: python

以下の書籍を参考にして時系列解析を勉強中です。

[時系列解析-自己回帰型モデル・状態空間モデル・異常検知](https://www.kyoritsu-pub.co.jp/bookdetail/9784320125018) / 島田直希 著

サンプルデータとサンプルコードでは動くのですが、
自分で作成した時系列データを代入するとエラーが出てしまいます。
ソースコードにはリンク先からアクセスできます。
3.3.3_particle_filter.ipynb

第3章の3.3.3 粒子フィルタを用いた線形季節調整モデルの実装例のところで、下記のコマンドを実行するとエラーが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

**ソースコード:**

```
# 観測値の次元数
n_dim_obs = 1
# トレンドの次元数
n_dim_trend = 2
# 季節成分の次元数
n_dim_series = 12
# 粒子数
n_particles = 200
# システムノイズの分散共分散行列の対角要素の値
system_sigma2 = 150

# 推移行列などの定義
n_dim_state, F, H, Q = FGHset(n_dim_trend,
                              n_dim_obs,
                              n_dim_series,
                              Q_sigma2=system_sigma2)

observation_sigma2 = 100
transition_func = lambda x: F.dot(x)
observation_func = lambda x: H.dot(x)
system_noise = GaussianNoise(Q)
observation_noise = GaussianNoise(np.eye(n_dim_obs)*observation_sigma2)

pf = ParticleFilter(n_dim_state=n_dim_state, 
                    n_dim_obs=n_dim_obs,
                    transition_func=transition_func,
                    observation_func=observation_func,
                    system_noise=system_noise,
                    observation_noise=observation_noise,
                    n_particles=n_particles)

n_train = 120
predicted_value = np.empty(len(y[:n_train]))
for i, d in enumerate(y[:n_train]):
    pf.update(d)
    predicted_value[i] = pf.predict()

rng = range(len(predicted_value))
plt.plot(rng, y[:n_train], label="observation")
plt.plot(rng, predicted_value, '--', label="predict")
```

自分で作成した時系列データは、
要素数132、取り得る値が8,000～50,000の月次データです。
データ形式は、サンプルデータと合わせています。
取り得る最大値を500以下にするとエラーは出ないので、
時系列データの値の大きさによるエラーだと思われます。
ただ、その場合どこを修正すればいいのかよくわからず、困っています。

エラーの詳細について追記します。

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-a33942154354> in <module>
     33 predicted_value = np.empty(len(y[:n_train]))
     34 for i, d in enumerate(y[:n_train]):
---> 35     pf.update(d)
     36     predicted_value[i] = pf.predict()
     37 

<ipython-input-141-5c9ab45cc0af> in update(self, y)
     70         self._update_particles()
     71         self._update_particles_weight(y)
---> 72         self._resample()
     73 
     74     def forecast(self):

<ipython-input-141-5c9ab45cc0af> in _resample(self)
    114 
    115         # 粒子の選定
--> 116         self.selected_idx = [np.where(cum>=p)[0][0] for p in pointers]
    117         self.particles = self.predicted_particles[:, self.selected_idx]
    118 

<ipython-input-141-5c9ab45cc0af> in <listcomp>(.0)
    114 
    115         # 粒子の選定
--> 116         self.selected_idx = [np.where(cum>=p)[0][0] for p in pointers]
    117         self.particles = self.predicted_particles[:, self.selected_idx]
    118 

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

エラーの出ているy, pf, d, rngは、
y.shape : (132,)
pf      :  <**main**.ParticleFilter at 0x228f28ba9c8>
d       : 28817.0
rng     : range(0,132)
となっています。

Comment: 最初にすべきは、エラーの出ている配列のshapeを確認する事です。
 axis 0 with size 0(0次軸のサイズが0)というのは、明らかにおかしいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーについて追記をしました。